# Notifications badge not taking up left position when changing direction to RTL

Tags: material-components-web

I have an issue in my code where RTL works everywhere except for notifications badges that always stays in the right top only

https://jsfiddle.net/t54xsrvq/

It works fine in the demo in 
https://material-ui.com/components/badges/#api

```
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header" dir="rtl">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="material-icons mdl-badge mdl-badge--overlap btn-badge" data-badge="5">
            <div class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--notifications" >
              <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
.
.
.
</div>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The code in the jsfiddle and in your question is not using Material-UI.

Comment: I updated to the right tags